# How to implement a Cryptographic Pseudo Random Function

Tags: reference-request, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

I need three pseudo random functions which all take  a 
seed S (t-bits long).

The functions should map from

1. $d$ bits to $d$ bits
2. $d$ bits to $1$ bit
3. $d$ bits to $t$ bits

$d$ is $10$ bits
$t$ is $2048$ bits

Can you link me to some c++ implementation(or any language) or tell me how to implement it?

Comment: Short answer? No. For (2) take  look at [hardcore bits](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/hardcore.xhtml) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-core_predicate))

Comment: With just 10 bits of input, an attacker simply precomputing all possible values of $d$ would render your values very predictable indeed - especially for 3

Comment: I prefer a two phase function: 1) *Extract* - Hash the seed and the input to a fixed size (say 256 bits) 2) *Expand* - Use a stream cipher to expand that key to whatever size you want. | You can use HKDF for this.

Answer (score 1):

1. $f_s: d \rightarrow d$ bits is a Pseudorandom Permutation  (see Luby-Rackoff Constructions)
2. $f_s: d \rightarrow 1$ bit is a Hardcore bit (see Goldreich Levin Theorem)
3. $f_s: d \rightarrow t$ bits is a Pseudorandom Generator. (assuming $t$ is a function of $d$)  (see Goldreich Goldwasser Micali)

(All these topics are coved in the Katz-Lindell book.)

With these constructions known, you'll be writing provably secure constructions for the crypto primitives.

Also, please forgive my abuse of notation here, when i write $f_s: x \rightarrow y$, what I really mean is $f: x \times s \rightarrow y$